# Unset an array value by having array of keys, which leads to it

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks pretty much like this:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'b' => [
            'classname1' => 'data1',
            'classname2' => 'data2' // This one must go away
        ],
        'classname3' => 'data3',
        1 => [ ... ]
    ],
    'a' => [ ... ],
    'classnameN' => 'dataN'
];
```

This array can have any keys (numeric or string) and can be any levels deep. The question is how to unset part of it by having an array, which values are leading to some data in the first array?

For example using `$definer = [0,'b','classname2'];` we must delete commented part of an array.

I have a solution on how to find, what I need to delete, but I've realised, that I don't know how to travel back and assign new value to initial array:

```
$array_traveler = $array;

for($i = 0; $i < count($definer) - 1; $i++) {
    $array_traveler = $array_traveler[$definer[$i]];
}
unset($array_traveler[$definer[count($definer) - 1]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "pointer"

```
$array_traveler = &$array;

for($i = 0; $i < count($definer) - 1; $i++) {
    $array_traveler = &$array_traveler[$definer[$i]];
}
unset($array_traveler[$definer[count($definer) - 1]]);
```

Comment: Yea, that kinda worked, but resulting array is now have a pointer in it too, instead of value
`&array(1) { ["classname1"]=> string(5) "data1" }`

Comment: this code changes array `$array` but `array_traveler`. the last is only pointer to the first

Comment: I mean `var_dump($array);` done after that `unset` shows `&` in the beggining of parent of the deleted item. Is it intended?

Comment: I've found that it is totally normal and ampersand there means that this part is referenced by some variable. You can just `unset($array_traveler)` to get rid of it. https://eval.in/525485